# Access to nodejs through apache

Tags: angularjs, node.js, apache, security, reverse-proxy

I'd like to add security on my nodejs application.

For this, I have added a proxyReverse with apache to access my node application with apache.
It's working, but **the problem is that i'm still able to access my node application without going through apache ...**

My node site is on mydomain:8080/html/site.html
I access to node with apache on mydomain/site

so what I want is redirect mydomain:8080/html/site.html to mydomain/site ...

But i'm scary to make an infinite call.

Here is my node **server.js**:

```
var express = require('express');
var port = 8080;
/*------------------------
        Configuration
 ------------------------*/
app = express();
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});

/* Port d'ecoute du serveur */
app.listen(port);
```

Here is my **apache2.conf**:

```
<VirtualHost 172.30.0.10:80 >
        ServerName "mydomain:80"
        UseCanonicalName Off


        ProxyPass /site http://mydomain:8080/html/site.html
        ProxyPassReverse /site http://mydomain:8080/html/site.html

        <Proxy *>
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
                Authtype Basic
                Authname "Password Required"
                AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/passwords
                Require valid-user
        </Proxy>

</VirtualHost>
```

I need your help and advices! thanks in advance for reading this !

Comment: you got any answer yet ???

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
app.listen(port);
```

to this:

```
app.listen(port, 'localhost');
```

and instead of `mydomain:8080` use `localhost:8080` in your Apache config.

This will tell your Node app to listen only on the loopback interface and it will not reply to any request originating from a different host than itself. But for that to work you have to change your proxy config to `localhost` because your proxy will not be able to connect to the Node app using a different interface than loopback even if it's on the same machine.

Another way to handle all that would be to filter the packets on the TCP/IP level but it's easier to bind to a specific interface in the first place.